# Assigning normal data types to Class.prototype

Tags: javascript

I was of the knowledge that prototype is shared between all class instances in JavaScript. Then what is the explanation of the below behavior.

```
 function Parent() {}
 Parent.prototype.a = 3
 var p1 = new Parent()
 var p2 = new Parent()
 p1.a
=> 3
 p2.a
=> 3
 p1.a = 10
=> 10
 p2.a
=> 3
```

I know normally we're supposed to put functions in prototype, but why is the above not changing value of `prototype.a` for all instances.

But the following works:

```
  function Parent () {}
  Parent.prototype.prop = {a:1}
  var p1 = new Parent()
  var p2 = new Parent()
  p1.prop.a
=> 1
  p2.prop.a
=> 1
  p1.prop.a = 10
=> 10
  p2.prop.a
=> 10
```

Why does it work with objects and not basic types?

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no inherent benefit to using the prototype to store normal data, and that it should be used sparingly because it's a bit confusing.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying out stuff

Comment: `p1.a = 10` is creating a *new property* on `p1`. `Parent.prototype` stays unaffected. Try `Parent.prototype.a = 10` and you will see the objects inheriting from it affected.

Comment: Why is it that when i print `p1.a` it uses the prototype but when i assign it creates a new property?